# OpenCV/C++ Multiple colour tracking

Tags: c++, opencv

Does anyone have any examples of tracking multiple colours using OpenCV/C++? I found some with python but not C++ yet. I've managed to track yellow by using :

```
IplImage *imgHSV= cvCreateImage (cvGetSize(img),8,3);
cvCvtColor(img,imgHSV,CV_BGR2HSV);

IplImage*imgThreshed =cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),8,1);

//track yellow
cvInRangeS(imgHSV,cvScalar(20,100,100), cvScalar(30,255,255), imgThreshed);

//saved the points 
double area=cvGetCentralMoment(moment, 0, 0);
double moment10=cvGetSpatialMoment(moment, 1, 0);
double moment01=cvGetSpatialMoment(moment, 0, 1);
```

I'm trying to do something similar with blue by doing :

```
cvInRangeS(imgHSV,cvScalar(100,100,100), cvScalar(120,255,255), imgblue);
```

Then save points:

```
double area1=cvGetCentralMoment(moment1, 0, 0);
double moment05=cvGetSpatialMoment(moment1, 1, 0);
double moment02=cvGetSpatialMoment(moment1, 0, 1);
```

//draw line

```
   static int posF=0;
    static int posE=0;

  posE=moment05/area1;
    posF=moment02/area1;

    int lastF=posF;
    int lastE=posE
 if (lastF>=0 && lastE>=0 && posF>=0 && posE>=0){

        cvLine(imgScribble, cvPoint(posF,posE),cvPoint(lastF,lastE), cvScalar(255,0,0),16);

    }
```

The points for blue is what I'm having trouble with. Any advice on tracking multiple colours and saving the points?
![yellow lines are tracking yellow and the blue dots are for blue but they should also be lines[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuzAu.png)

Comment: 1. Check http://docs.opencv.org/genindex.html - -  - 2. Describe better what you mean with "troubles"

Comment: I'm having trouble saving points that are "blue points" and points that are "yellow points" . The two colours are getting somewhat confused

Comment: can you post a test image and what exactly is confusing you?